# Как лучше всего кадрировать background-image?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Хотелось бы получить пару ответов на вопросы связанные с обрезанием заднего фона посредством jquery.

1. Обязательно ли преобразовывать задник в base64 для работы с ним? Как это делают многие ресурсы.
2. Можно ли обрезать задник если ширина фиксирована, т.е. сверху и снизу, все кроме нужной области(всегда заданного размера).
   Вроде бы все crop плагины не работают с задниками и захламлены лишним функционалом.
   Да и canvas использовать по мне это лишнее.

Дайте советы, чтобы не тратить время на поиски решений которые могут в итоге оказаться не подходящими. Всем спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите на свойство CSS `background-size: cover` или `contain` если вы это имеете виду. base64 для background точно не нужен, равче что вы хотите картинку с инпута взять.

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду под "обрезать background-image" ? если Вам нужно просто отобразить какую то часть изображения, а остальное скрыть то используйте CSS-свойства: `background-size, background-position`. Если же Вы говорите об обрезании изображений для последующего сохранения в файл, то `canvas` реализация самое то

Comment: @ДмитрийМирошниченко  Посмотрев несколько примеров разных ресурсов обратил внимание, что они перегоняют в base64. Тут и стал вопрос работать с локальным файлом в base64, а затем после нужных операций отправлять на сервер. Или(как я сейчас думаю) грузить изображение на сервер, затем пользователь изменяет его. А дальше перезаписывать старое.

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach Хотелось бы именно обрезать. Значит без канвы никуда? Ясно. Я не могу юзать background-size, потому что исходное изображение больше по высоте области необходимой видимости.

Comment: @user309309 Из вопросы было не совсем понятно чтобы вы именно хотите реализовать кадрирование на клиенте. В таком случае Вам действительно нужно работать с base64. Также я бы советовал посмотреть на готовые решения типа: https://dev.vizuina.com/cropper/

Comment: Поправил название темы. Crop не подойдёт, он не работает с background насколько я знаю. Разве нельзя ли имея координаты отступа сверху, отрезать кусок средствами js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь когда требования более менее ясны можно что то советовать:

> Пользователь хочет поставить фон. Он Грузит изображение 1600x1200. Я
>   его сразу преобразуются под мою область видения, это 1184x890(если
>   правильно помню). Область отображаемого фона на странице 1184x300. При
>   том что пользователь может захотеть сдвинуть вертикально изображение
>   на любой отступить в пределах этих 890px. Так что по факту фон
>   отображаемый на странице должен иметь смещение, которое указал
>   пользовать.

Если Вы не хотите заниматься "оптимизацией на спичках" и ресурс хранилища для загружаемых картинок не сильно дорогой, то я бы посоветовал не обрезать картинки вовсе. Просто сохранять данные о картинке и её настройках. Для этого можно использовать какую-то библиотеку с **drag-n-drop** и другими фишками, и из неё получать данные в виде:

```
{
  "src": "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x1200",
  "top": 352,
  "left": -520
}
```

Сохранять данные где-то в БД и потом рендерить, там где нужно следующим образом:

```js
const getImage = () => {
  return {
    "src": "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x1200",
    "top": -321,
    "left": -100
  }
};

const setImageAsBg = (element, imgConfig) => {
  if (element && imgConfig) {
    const { src, top, left } = imgConfig;
    element.style.backgroundImage = `url(${src})`;
    element.style.backgroundPosition = `${left}px ${top}px`;
  } else {
    console.warn("Haven't 'element' or 'imgConfig' argument");
  }
};

const bannerEl = document.getElementsByClassName("image-container")[0];
const imageData = getImage();

setImageAsBg(bannerEl, imageData);
```

```css
.image-container {
  background-color: red;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  width: 1800px;
  height: 350px;
}

.full-image-container {
  margin: 3em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container"></div>
<div class="full-image-container">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x1200" alt="full size">
</div>
```

Comment: Хм, интересное решение. Подумаю, поэтому поводу. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

> Посмотрите на свойство CSS background-size: cover или contain если вы это имеете виду. 
>  **@Дмитрий Мирошниченко**

**`background-size: cover`** - Масштабирует изображение с сохранением пропорций так, чтобы его ширина или высота равнялась ширине или высоте блока.

Пример:

```css
.cover {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/8633/nature-tree-green-pine.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
}

.cover.vert {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.cover.hori {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover vert"></div>
<div class="cover hori"></div>
```

---

**`background-size: contain`** - Масштабирует изображение с сохранением пропорций таким образом, чтобы картинка целиком поместилась внутрь блока.

Пример:

```css
.contain {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/8633/nature-tree-green-pine.jpg') no-repeat center center / contain;
}

.contain.vert {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.contain.hori {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain vert"></div>
<div class="contain hori"></div>
```

[Источник](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size)

Comment: Это ещё раз скажу не подойдёт. Так как область видения всегда будет, одна и та же. И если вдруг область видения надо будет сдвинуть на ? Пикселей, при одном и том же заднике. Толку от такого решения 0.

Comment: @user309309 Если нужно сдвинуть то вы используете `background-position: 10px 10px`. Просто приведите пример. Я уже запутался что Вы конкретно хотите.

Comment: Хм. Только сейчас до меня стал доходить смысл этого решения. А как считаете сильно на загрузку будет влиять если к примеру при области виденья 1184x300 будет задник к примеру 1184x1200 ?

Comment: Как я понимаю в таком случае, я буду работать не с картинкой, а с координатами отступа сверху. И писать в базу именно их при выбранном изображении.

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach вы просили пример. Пользователь хочет поставить фон. Он Грузит изображение 1600x1200. Я его сразу преобразуются под мою область видения, это 1184x890(если правильно помню). Область отображаемого фона на странице 1184x300. При том что пользователь может захотеть сдвинуть  вертикально изображение на любой отступить в пределах этих 890px. Так что по факту фон отображаемый на странице должен иметь смещение, которое указал пользовать.

Comment: @user309309, при текущих характеристиках устройств, вопрос "сильная ли нагрузка" неактуален.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо. О таком варианте не думал.